# Nexus 7 Android 6.0 Audio Output through USB OTG

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I have a 2nd Generation Nexus 7 connected to my car. The 3.5mm headphone jack is not accessible the way i've mounted it and I have a power USB hub connected via an OTG cable with some devices connected. I need to get a Audio cable output so that I can plug in to the 3.5 aux input of my car. Can anyone tell me if the Nexus 7 supports USB audio output and what kind of cable will work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.  The only audio output is the 3.5mm jack.  Just get a TRRS (4-wire - a 3-wire won't work) extension as long as you need, male on one end to go into the Nexus 7, female on the other end to plug in whatever you want to plug in.